# Finding missing time intervals from data

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a list of dates in a CSV file, I want to find and add the missing intervals in one hour time slots of the day.

The data looks like:

```
id  city     reading date 
33  US-Ohio  06/18/2011 23:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 00:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 01:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 02:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 06:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 07:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 08:00:00  
34  US-NYC   06/19/2011 06:00:00  
34  US-NYC   06/19/2011 08:00:00
```

So, the missing data that needs to be inserted is

```
id  city     reading date 
33  US-Ohio  06/18/2011 23:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 00:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 01:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 02:00:00  
             06/19/2011 03:00:00  
             06/19/2011 04:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 06:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 07:00:00  
33  US-Ohio  06/19/2011 08:00:00  
34  US-NYC   06/19/2011 06:00:00  
             06/19/2011 07:00:00  
34  US-NYC   06/19/2011 08:00:00
```

I have already converted it to datetime using pandas, using the code:

```
games['reading_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(games['reading_date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

The dates are repeated, so setting an index and resampling does not work, because there are different missing times in different cities and the index is repeated multiple times 
I just need to add these missing hourly intervals and keep all the other columns blank. How do I do this in python?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  It seems straightforward: you iterate through the hours of the day.  If the current hour isn't in the data frame, you add the `NaN` entry for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer for updated data set:

group by id & city and apply the `asfreq` function.

```
df.groupby(['id', 'city'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('reading date').asfreq('1H').reset_index())

# outputs:

                         id      city
  reading date
0 2011-06-18 23:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 00:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 01:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 02:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 03:00:00   NaN       NaN
  2011-06-19 04:00:00   NaN       NaN
  2011-06-19 05:00:00   NaN       NaN
  2011-06-19 06:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 07:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
  2011-06-19 08:00:00  33.0   US-Ohio
1 2011-06-19 06:00:00  34.0    US-NYC
  2011-06-19 07:00:00   NaN       NaN
  2011-06-19 08:00:00  34.0    US-NYC
```

edit: original answer

Ensure that `Column 1` is a date time.

Then, set index to 'Column 1' and use pandas.DataFrame.asFreq

```
df['Column 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column 1'])

df.set_index('Column 1').asfreq('1H')

# Returns:

                    Column 2
Column 1
2011-06-18 23:00:00        a
2011-06-19 00:00:00      NaN
2011-06-19 01:00:00        b
2011-06-19 02:00:00        c
2011-06-19 03:00:00      NaN
2011-06-19 04:00:00      NaN
2011-06-19 05:00:00        d
2011-06-19 06:00:00      NaN
2011-06-19 07:00:00        e
2011-06-19 08:00:00        f
```

Comment: updated the question. There are repeated dates for different cities so I cant resample duplicate indices so i get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: your solution adds a blank row even for time. It doesnt fill in the missing time interval

Comment: i don't know what your last comment means. good luck solving this problem.

Comment: Had to reset_index

Comment: I also want it to complete the days of the month that are not present. for example, complete june for all 30 days even though only 19 days are available in my table.

Comment: can you help me even finish the days? So if my month ends at 03/21/2018, I want to add empty rows for all days and hour intervals from 03/22 - 03/31